# Business Suite vs S/4HANA

Tags: sap-erp, s4hana, sap-crm

What is the difference between S/4HANA & Business Suite? Is it true to say Business Suite includes ERP, CRM, SRM, SCM and S/4HANA is only the next generation of ERP?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably to broad for a short answer here.

You might go to https://open.sap.com and start with the course "SAP S/4HANA in a Nutshell". It's free, no strings attached.

S/4 HANA is intended as a successor. So SAP thinks S/4 HANA is better. But not everything is implemented yet, especially some industry specific processes.

So you can spend a few more hours on https://open.sap.com with the free course "Implementation of SAP S/4HANA". Here you learn where to get all the documentation you need and how to check if and how S/4 HANA supports the processes you need and you get a deeper understanding.

This is because you can't answer the question "Does S/4 HANA include ERP". You answer this question for each of your main processes that you use in your company.